# How do I find the size of a table in Cassandra Keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra

I have used this command to get the size of a table

```
nodetool cfstats -- <Keyspace>.<table name>
```

But, I am not sure whether it is right or wrong as if I upload more rows into my table, "Space Used" is not changing only  "Memtable data size" is changing.

I just wanna know how to find the size of a table in cassandra keyspaces.

Answer (score 0):

When a node receives a mutation (a write), it first gets persisted in a commit log then written to a memtable. The mutations/writes are not persisted to a SSTable until the memtable is flushed to disk.

If you want to force the memtables to be flushed to disk, run:

```
$ nodetool flush -- ks_name table_name
```

For more info, see [How data is written in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html). Cheers!